# Flutter : single border with border radius on Card

Tags: flutter, widget, border

**Issue** : trouble setting **border-radius** along with **single border** *(right border)* on the Card widget.

so far i've got :

```
//for single border
return Card(
  shape: const Border(
    right: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(179, 232, 5, 5), width: 3),
  ),
  child:...,
);
```

```
//for border-radius
return Card(
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
   side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 3),
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
  ),
  child:...,
);
```

I need a combination of both, to have a card with :

- Border radius on all sides
- Border only on the right side

like this - [image: expected output]

Comment: you want above design?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
Card(
      elevation: 2,
      child: ClipPath(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              right: BorderSide(
                color: Color.fromARGB(179, 232, 5, 5),
                width: 5,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Thanks.

so in short we can't use only shape property to achieve this? i mean this seems a bit hard to grasp.